# Stashing and Control Aware mailboxes in Akka

Tags: akka, actor

In my application, I have one actor which need to stash messages when waiting for some operations to complete and at the same time it needs to support high priority messages (Control Messages).

The stash trait requires a `Dequeue` type of mailbox and I couldn't find if it makes sense to have a *control-aware dequeue mailbox*. Is it possible, and if not, why would I not store the messages I can't handle in the state of the actor?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this question as well since I wanted to get the behaviour of stash but with some additional functionality.

As far as I can tell there is no good reason not to implement your own stashing strategy. You can store incoming messages into a priority queue or whatever works for your purposes, then process them as needed.

I use 'become' to change the receiving state of the actor to stashing then back to processing, selecting the best message to proceed with.

One caveat that I picked up from Akka's Stash implementation, is that if your actor restarts you get a chance to recover anything from the state of your actor. So if you need to, you could handle preRestart by logging out any lost commands or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: how do you "replay" the messages including the sender though?

Comment: In my case I store commands in the actor that are replayed but don't message back to the original sender. You could store the sender as well though since it's an actorref

Comment: actually the ! supports an implicit sender

Comment: It does, but I mean when I save commands to execute later I also save the sender so I can send it to the original actorref